# How can I ask icinga2 from the command line to execute a single-time check of everything?

Tags: icinga2

I would like to test my whole system config.

I think it is not a very unusual feature. I want icinga2 to check everything and show me the results.

Ideally, notifications shouldn't be called, I only want to see the results in the standard output/stderr, but it would be also with notifications okay.

Reasonable answers saying that there is no such feature without digging its source code, are also acceptable.

Comment: Note: digging icinga2 documents and googling for that results *everything*, except this very trivial and obvious feature.

Comment: If not sure about Icinga but as it is forked from Nagios, on Nagios,you would need to get a list of all services on each server and then parse the data in a loop, executing /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H <hostname> -c <checkname>

Comment: @RamanSailopal It calls a check plugin from the command line. But I want icinga to call *all checks*, for all hosts.

Comment: In Nagios, you can click on the host name and then "Schedule a check of all services on this host"

Comment: @RamanSailopal That's fine. Also icinga has a web gui. But I would like to do that from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature and if you consider everything you'll understand why.  Icinga checks are not all active ones. Some are passive and are reported when an external system decides. Some rely on distributed monitors to check and report back. And some rely on multiple cycles to determine state.
While one could possibly design such a feature for Icinga (and assume some set of defaults to give you what you seek), it has not been done.

Comment: In my interpretation it means: although it would be the most handy method to debug all the icinga check, it was simply not developed. Thanks (also the *no* answer is useful), if no better answer arrives, you will have the bounty.

Comment: That's not what I was saying at all.